# Client bound access token

Tags: oauth-2.0

Looking at the Oauth2 specification, it says in [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-46):

```
... the refresh token is bound to the client to which it was issued.
```

However, I can't find anything in the specification the explicitly states that the token should be bound to the requesting client also. I am assuming this to be the case, and the [Introspection Extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) seems to support that assumption, but I want to know if that is correct.

As an example, say I am using two applications that use Google as the Oauth2 Authorization Server. I'm assuming that Google will issue two different tokens, one to each application, and that the tokens can only be used by the client to which they were issued because they are bound to that client.

Answer (score 2):

An access token can have various implementations. The one that is most widely adopted today is the "Bearer" token, in RFC 6750 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750. A Bearer token is not bound to the Client on purpose: it makes it easy to implement, lowers the barrier for adoption and caters for a wide range of use cases.

Assuming that a Bearer token cannot be easily stolen, it is acceptable to avoid binding it to a specific Client: the intended Client could indeed share the access token with another Client but it could just as well share the data that the access token permits access to if the token *was* bound.

In environments that demand higher security one could use a token that is bound to the Client as defined in RFC 7800 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it is implicit in the specification that the access token should only be used by the application that the user authorized. Putting it differently - having something other than the authorized application use the token to access user data is pretty much the definition of a privacy failure, and is what authorization protocols are explicitly designed to prevent in the first place.

Now, in practice, I think that having one application use the access token from another would work fine in many OAuth 2.0 implementations. I don't thing the Token Introspection extension is widely used, and most access tokens are designed to be self-validating. Indeed, that's the reason why token stealing is a security risk. By contrast, the refresh token should only be useful when combined with the client secret, so it's "bound" to the client technically as well as philosophically.